# Print common values in columns using bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have file with two columns

```
apple apple
ball cat
cat hat
dog delta
```

I need to extract values that are common in two columns (occur in both columns) like

```
apple apple
cat cat
```

There is no ordering in items in each column.

Comment: common means a value which is coming more than 1 time in a file, could you please elaborate here?

Comment: Also kindly do add your efforts too which you had done in order to try to solve your problem too in your post, as we all are here to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk '{a[$1];b[$2]} END{for(k in a) if(k in b) print k}' file
apple
cat
```

to print the values twice change to `print k,k`

with `sort/join`

```
$ join <(cut -d' ' -f1 file | sort) <(cut -d' ' -f2 file | sort)
apple
cat
```

perhaps,

```
$ function f() { cut -d' ' -f"$1" file | sort; }; join <(f 1) <(f 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '
{
  col1[$1]++;
  col2[$2]++;
}
END{
  for(i in col1){
    if(col2[i]){
      while(++count<=(col1[i]+col2[i])){
         printf("%s%s",i,count==(col1[i]+col2[i])?ORS:OFS)}
      count=""}
  }
}' Input_file
```

***NOTE:*** It will print the values if found in both the columns exactly number of times they are occurring in both the columns too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I can use unix commands:

```
cut -d' ' -f2 fil | egrep `cut -d' ' -f1 < fil | paste -sd'|'` -
```

Basically what this does is this:

The second `cut` command collects all the words in the first column. The `paste` command joins them with a pipe (i.e. `dog|cat|apple`).

The first `cut` command takes the second column of words in the list and pipes them into a regexp-enabled `egrep` command.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the closest I could get. Maybe you could loop through whole file and print when it reaches another occurrence.

## Code

```
cat file.txt | gawk   '$1==$2 {print $1,"=",$2}'
```

or

```
gawk '$1==$2 {print $1,"=",$2}' file.txt
```